# Need advice on storing pincode system (Zip code) and Shipping company Service Details

Tags: mariadb, table

I am in the process of creating a system that could identify shipping companies (Fedex, UPS, etc.) from a given pincode (zip code) for a e-commerce platform.

The shipping companies will provide a list of pincodes where they provide pickup and delivery. So when we get an order for a product, with the pincode of the seller and with pincode of the buyer I need to get a list of shipping companies who provides both these services (i.e. pickup and delivery).

My initial plan is to create a table structure like the following one:

Table shipping_companies

```
id | company
1  | Fedex
2  | UPS
3  | DHL
```

Table pincodes

```
id | pincode | shipping_ids_pickup | shipping_ids_delivery
1  | 263152  |         1,2         |       2,3
```

The pincodes table will have the pincodes and will have two columns one for pickup and another for delivery.

So when a user purchases a product I need to find a shipping company that has pickup from the sellers location and also has delivery at buyers location.

If we are adding another shipping company in the future I can update the  shipping_ids_pickup, shipping_ids_delivery for a pincode by appending the id.

Can someone suggest a better solution. Is there any issue with current approach.